# Unable to click first radio button in list with mouse but can use up and down arrow keys to select it

Tags: html, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have a question with a list of answers in a CSHTML form. The answers are in the form of a list of radio buttons. When I try to select an answer while demoing or after publishing the website, I am unable to select the first option "Definitely Not" with a mouse click, but for some reason I can select any of the other radio buttons, and use my up and down arrow keys to select the "Definitely Not" option. I'm not sure why I can't use a mouse click to select that radio button.

On clicking any of the other 4 options, followup questions are made visible via Javascript, whereas select "Definitely Not" is supposed to hide those questions. Here is the HTML code:

```html
            <p>Q26. How likely are you to move homes in the near future?</p>
            <ul class="survey_answer_list">
                <li style="list-style-type: none">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Q21" value="definitely not" id="Q21_df" onclick="return followup_q21_df()"> Definitely Not
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li style="list-style-type: none">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Q21" value="possibly" id="Q21_p" onclick="return followup_q21_p()"> Possibly
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li style="list-style-type: none">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Q21" value="maybe" id="Q21_m" onclick="return followup_q21_m()"> Maybe
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li style="list-style-type: none">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Q21" value="probably" id="Q21_pr" onclick="return followup_q21_pr()"> Probably
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li style="list-style-type: none">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Q21" value="definitely" id="Q21_d" onclick="return followup_q21_d()"> Definitely
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <script>
                function followup_q21_df() {
                    var q21_df = document.getElementById("Q21_df");

                    if (q21_df.checked) {
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.visibility = "hidden";
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.height = "0";
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup_Q1_error").style.visibility = "hidden";
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup_Q1_error").style.height = "0";
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup_Q2_error").style.visibility = "hidden";
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup_Q2_error").style.height = "0";
                    }
                }

                function followup_q21_m() {
                    var q21_m = document.getElementById("Q21_m");

                    if (q21_m.checked) {
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.height = "auto";
                    }
                }

                function followup_q21_p() {
                    var q21_p = document.getElementById("Q21_p");

                    if (q21_p.checked) {
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.height = "auto";
                    }
                }

                function followup_q21_pr() {
                    var q21_pr = document.getElementById("Q21_pr");

                    if (q21_pr.checked) {
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.height = "auto";
                    }
                }

                function followup_q21_d() {
                    var q21_d = document.getElementById("Q21_d");

                    if (q21_d.checked) {
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById("Q21_followup").style.height = "auto";
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: could be something to do with your `followup_q21_df` js function?  Please can you edit your question to show the code

Comment: I added the JavaScript code. However, I tried swapping the position of the "Definitely Not" button with that of the "Maybe" option, and tried clicking it, it didn't work. It seems its the 1st button of the list that's not working regardless of which one is there.

Comment: I figured it out. I'm using different submit buttons in this form based on different scenarios of followup questions. One of the buttons, not associated with the question related to the radio button list, although it was set as invisible, it seems setting height to 0 didn't entirely hide it and it was literally blocking me from selecting "Definitely Not". I now used display:none instead of visibility:none and height:0, and its working fine.